# Selecting All Products In Order By Category

Tags: php, mysql, model

I am using OpenCart 1.5 and I have my general categories witch displays the products fine but I have created a category called **View All ** this has an id of 65. When this category is selected it displays all products fine but not in order of what category that they are in.  How could I achieve this?

I have a feeling the adjustment will be made to the getProducts function

I have posted my MVC [Here](https://gist.github.com/1228467)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm honestly not familiar with OpenCart, but it seems to me that if you need that specific order just for one category , you could patch up your getProducts function just a tiny bit to resolve it for that specific situation.